# Is there any alternative available for react-native-fs library in React native?

Tags: react-native, readfile

I am reading large json files in React Native code but its giving me unacceptable performance hit. This performance problem for large files is also mentioned in their [documentation](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs/blob/master/README.md#promise-readfilepath--encoding).

Is there any alternate available which can help me to read files from document directory without hitting performance ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now for reading file it seems like react-native-fs is the only library available. It works fine with small files but in case of large file you may face a huge performance hit.
For better performance write native module to access files and you'll feel fair amount of performance enhancement. In this way if you're supporting both iOS and Android you have to write code in Java and objective-c as well.

Comment: If you're going to have to write your own native module, wouldn't it be better to try to fix the problem in the react-native-fs code?

Answer (score 3):

[react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) purports to address this with `readStream`, and the react-native-fs maintainers [consider](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs/issues/228) fetch-blob to be the better library anymore (name not withstanding).